# ¿Por qué me sale el error 303: Subíndice (0) fuera de rango?

Tags: pseint

Tenemos que hacer un programa para un minimarket que calcule el resultado de la compra y al devolverle el cambio diga de cuánto es cada billete que se le devolvió.

Yo ya hice una base y en la línea 96 me da un error:

> (Lin 96 (inst 1): ERROR 303: Subindice (0) fuera de rango (1...4))

y no sé como arreglarlo.

Esta es la línea 96:

```
cantidad_bill_mon(i) <- trunc(cantidad_entera / (monedas(indice_monedas) / 100))
```

```
Algoritmo sin_titulo
    Dimension  productos(1000)
    NUMERO_BILLETES <- 7
    NUMERO_MONEDAS <- 4
    TOTAL <- NUMERO_BILLETES + NUMERO_MONEDAS
    
    //arreglo de billetes
    dimension billetes(NUMERO_BILLETES)
    

    billetes(1)<-100000
    billetes(2)<-50000
    billetes(3)<-20000
    billetes(4)<-10000
    billetes(5)<-5000
    billetes(6)<-2000
    billetes(7)<-1000
    
    //arreglo de monedas
    dimension monedas(NUMERO_MONEDAS)
    
    //las cantidades estan en centimos
    
    monedas(1)<-500
    monedas(2)<-200
    monedas(3)<-100
    monedas(4)<-50
    
    
    dimension cantidad_bill_mon(TOTAL)
    
    //Indices para los arreglos de billetes y monedas
    indice_billetes<-0
    indice_monedas<-0
    Escribir "Desea Ingresar s/n?"
    Leer ing
    Escribir "001","papa"," = ","2000","la libra"

    Escribir "002","arroz"," = ","1500","la libra"
    
    Escribir "003","azucar"," = ","800","la libra"
    
    Escribir "004","sal"," = ","1000","la libra"
    papa="001"
    arroz= "002"
    Azucar ="003"
    sal ="004"
    

    Mientras (ing = "s" o ing = "S") Hacer
        
        Escribir "Digite el codigo del producto que desea llevar"
        Leer product
        Escribir "Digite la cantidad de libras que desea"
        leer cant
        
        si (product = "001")  Entonces
            v_papa=cant*2000
        FinSi
        
        si product= "002" Entonces
            V_arroz=cant*1500
        FinSi
        si product= "003" Entonces
            V_azucar=cant*800
        FinSi
        si product= "004" Entonces
            V_sal=cant*1000
        FinSi
        
        
        Escribir "Desea llevar otro producto s/n?"
        Leer ing
    FinMientras
    suma=V_papa+V_arroz+V_azucar+V_sal
    Escribir "con cuanto va a cancelar recibida"
    leer pago
    si pago >= suma Entonces
        Resta=pago-suma
        Escribir "la suma de sus productos es : ",suma;
        Escribir "su devuelta es: ",Resta;
        Si Resta > 0 Entonces
            cantidad_entera <- trunc(Resta)
            cantidad_decimal <- trunc(((Resta - cantidad_entera) *100) + 0.1)
            
        Para i<-1 Hasta TOTAL-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
                
            Si i<NUMERO_BILLETES Entonces
                cantidad_bill_mon(i) <- trunc(cantidad_entera / billetes(i))
                cantidad_entera <- cantidad_entera MOD billetes(i)
                indice_billetes <- indice_billetes +1
                    
            Sino
                    
                Si indice_monedas>=0 y indice_monedas<=1 Entonces
                cantidad_bill_mon(i) <- trunc(cantidad_entera / (monedas(indice_monedas) / 100))
                cantidad_entera <- cantidad_entera MOD (monedas(indice_monedas) /100)
                Sino
                    cantidad_bill_mon(i) <- trunc(cantidad_decimal / monedas(indice_monedas))
                    cantidad_decimal <- cantidad_decimal MOD monedas(indice_monedas)
                Fin Si
        indice_monedas <- indice_monedas + 1
    Fin Si
                
        Fin Para
        indice_billetes<-0
        indice_monedas<-0
        Para i<-0 Hasta TOTAL-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Si i<NUMERO_BILLETES Entonces
                Si cantidad_bill_mon(i) > 0 Entonces
                    Escribir "Cantidad de ",billetes(indice_billetes), "es de: ",cantidad_bill_mon(i)           
                    Fin Si
                    indice_billetes <- indice_billetes + 1
                Sino
                    Si cantidad_bill_mon(i) > 0 Entonces
                        Escribir "Cantidad de ",(monedas(indice_monedas) / 100), " es de: ",cantidad_bill_mon(i)            
                    Fin Si
                    indice_monedas <- indice_monedas + 1
            Fin Si
                
        Fin Para
        
    FinSi
        
        
    SiNo
        escribir "Falta dinero"
    FinSi
    
    
    
    
    
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en pseint, arreglos empiezan a 1, y da 0 al indice indice_monedas. https://odelys2003.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/arreglosenpseint-100915151154-phpapp02.pdf página 1.